# why normalization range is not between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, machine-learning, normalization

This is my code. I am trying to apply normalization to a dataset but I can see the output is not scaled between 0 and 1. Am I missing something here?
As this code works with iris dataset. Doesn't Normalization returns scaled value between 0 and 1 always?

```
# Normalize the data attributes for the boston dataset.
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn import preprocessing
# load the iris dataset
dataset = load_boston()
print(iris.data.shape)
# separate the data from the target attributes
X = dataset.data
y = dataset.target
# normalize the data attributes
normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(X)



normalized_X[:5]
```

output:

```
array([[1.26388341e-05, 3.59966795e-02, 4.61957387e-03, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.07590075e-03, 1.31487871e-02, 1.30387972e-01, 8.17924550e-03,
        1.99981553e-03, 5.91945396e-01, 3.05971776e-02, 7.93726783e-01,
        9.95908132e-03],
       [5.78529889e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 1.49769546e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
        9.93520754e-04, 1.36021253e-02, 1.67140272e-01, 1.05222110e-02,
        4.23676228e-03, 5.12648235e-01, 3.77071843e-02, 8.40785474e-01,
        1.93620036e-02],
       [5.85729947e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 1.51744622e-02, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.00662274e-03, 1.54212886e-02, 1.31139977e-01, 1.06609718e-02,
        4.29263427e-03, 5.19408747e-01, 3.82044450e-02, 8.43137761e-01,
        8.64965806e-03],
       [7.10489715e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 4.78488594e-03, 0.00000000e+00,
        1.00526503e-03, 1.53599229e-02, 1.00526503e-01, 1.33059337e-02,
        6.58470542e-03, 4.87268201e-01, 4.10446638e-02, 8.66174100e-01,
        6.45301131e-03],
       [1.50596596e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 4.75453408e-03, 0.00000000e+00,
        9.98888353e-04, 1.55874565e-02, 1.18209058e-01, 1.32215305e-02,
        6.54293681e-03, 4.84177324e-01, 4.07843061e-02, 8.65630540e-01,
        1.16246177e-02]])
```

Comment: Your output `normalized_X[:5]` contains only numbers between 0 and 1. Potentially you've missed the scientific notation?

Comment: @AidenRay my bad I've missed that one. Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you say the value are not between 0 and 1?

Normalization doesn't mean `min=0` and `max=1`... it means that each non-zero vector will be scaled so that its norm (by default L2 norm) is 1.

In other words for each vector the sum of the square of each coordinate will be 1.

For example considering your last vector we can see

```
In [1]: x = [1.50596596e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 4.75453408e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 
   ...:         9.98888353e-04, 1.55874565e-02, 1.18209058e-01, 1.32215305e-02, 
   ...:         6.54293681e-03, 4.84177324e-01, 4.07843061e-02, 8.65630540e-01, 
   ...:         1.16246177e-02]                                                                   

In [2]: sum(c**2 for c in x)                                                                      
Out[2]: 0.9999999993530653

In [3]:
```

Answer (score 2):

Normalize will not always end up with values between 0-1.

Use MinMaxScaler instead to have values between 0-1:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
normalized_X = scaler.transform(data)
```